# Case sensitivity is not working as expected in Secondary Index in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I used the secondary index in one of the columns in Cassandra,

**NOTE: That column is also a clustering key.**

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX testPoolName_idx ON Keyspace.TestPool (name) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

I believe case_sensitive 'false' as Case In-Sensitivity, When I perform the following query, I am able to see it tries to match the exact case (i.e) It has the value as 'TestName' but When I try to execute the following query it is not able to retrieve the data,

```
Select * from TestPool WHERE "partitionId" =  'partitionId' AND "name" LIKE  '%test%';
```

It succeeded for the following query,

```
Select * from TestPool WHERE "partitionId" =  'partitionId' AND "name" LIKE  '%Test%';
```

Could somebody say why and what is wrong in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case_sensitive` is not valid option for `standardAnalyzer`, it is for `NonTokenizingAnalyzer`.

[Valid StandardAnalyzer Options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateCustomIndex.html#cqlCreateCustomIndex__sasiStandardAnalyzer)

Since value is `TestName`, searching `%Test%` works.

By default `tokenization_normalize_lowercase` and `tokenization_normalize_uppercase` are false, hence it will do case sensitive search.

Comment: What is the difference between standardAnalyzer and NonTokenizingAnalyzer

Comment: The NonTokenizingAnalyzer is used for cases where the text is not analyzed, but case normalization or sensitivity is required. The StandardAnalyzer is used for analysis that involves stemming, case normalization, case sensitivity, skipping common words like "and" and "the", and localization of the language used to complete the analysis.

Comment: please help in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219277/chinese-language-in-cassandra