# Chinese language in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I used the chinese letters in Cassandra and it seems the data is entered properly like below,

```
SELECT * FROM user;

 user_id | user_name    | user_phone
---------+--------------+-------------
      23 |      uSer23, | 12345678910
       5 |       uSer5^ | 12345678910
      28 |     uSer28名 | 12345678910
      10 |      uSer10- | 12345678910
      16 |      uSer16{ | 12345678910
      13 |      uSer13= | 12345678910
      30 |   uSer30一些 | 12345678910
      11 |      uSer11_ | 12345678910
       1 |       uSer1@ | 12345678910
      19 |      uSer19" | 12345678910
       8 |       uSer8( | 12345678910
       0 |       uSer0! | 12345678910
       2 |       uSer2# | 12345678910
       4 |       uSer4% | 12345678910
      18 |      uSer18[ | 12345678910
      15 |      uSer15} | 12345678910
      22 |      uSer22< | 12345678910
      27 |      uSer27/ | 12345678910
      20 |      uSer20: | 12345678910
       7 |       uSer7* | 12345678910
       6 |       uSer6& | 12345678910
      29 |     uSer29称 | 12345678910
       9 |       uSer9) | 12345678910
      14 |      uSer14| | 12345678910
      26 |      uSer26? | 12345678910
      21 |      uSer21; | 12345678910
      17 |      uSer17] | 12345678910
      31 | uSer31区中文 | 12345678910
      24 |      uSer24> | 12345678910
      25 |      uSer25. | 12345678910
      12 |      uSer12+ | 12345678910
       3 |       uSer3$ | 12345678910
```

I created a index for 'user_name' field like below,

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX user_nontoken_idx ON QCS.user (user_name) 
  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' 
  WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 
    'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer',
    'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

When I do a search using those chinese word, It is searched successfully.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name LIKE '%称%';
```

How does it actually works? How Cassandra has the capability to store chinese?

Comment: It seems like you are using text data type for `user_name` field. text data type is `UTF-8 encoded string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the text is represented in Cassandra as `UTF-8` as it was mentioned in comment.

For your question the main work is done by SASI that gets the data from text column, and apply analyzer to it - and in most cases, for analyzer, the Chinese characters are like other characters.  Although if you plan to index text columns, then you may need to look to `StandardAnalyzer`. But for user names, or something like, `NonTokenizingAnalyzer` could be better.

Comment: Is there a way to store the key with localization in Cassandra?

Comment: @Ashraful Islam your help is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean the key with localization?

Comment: Please check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276508/cassandra-status-check-using-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

The ability of understanding language specific strings, comes from the fact that the "TEXT" datatype (of "user_name" column here) is

> "UTF-8 encoded string"

in Cassandra. Comparing this with if the column "user_name" would have been stored as "ascii" then it understands only **US-ASCII character string** set.